# How to build and run a Unity project when ruining unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

I'm making a multiplayer game and to test it I need to load a specific scene in both the unit tester and standalone simultaneously.

Using constants, One Client would act as a sender, while the other acting as a receiver. I would test the received data against predefined data.

I tried doing the following test script but got the following errors.

```cs
private const string SCENE_PATH = "Assets/Tests/PlayMode/Assets/Scenes/Scene.unity";
private const string BUILD_PATH = "Build/Testing.exe";

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void OneTimeSetUp()
{
    Debug.Log("OneTimeSetUp Base");
    string[] scenes = { SCENE_PATH };
    BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, BUILD_PATH, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64, BuildOptions.None);
}
```

[image]

Comment: hm thats not really what a unit test should do at all...

Comment: yes, but the UI and assert are very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Just run build and run and then run the tests.

Comment: That is the thing I want to avoid.

Comment: Should be doing this though.. You can do it automated in CI.. But Unit Test is not where this should happen.. In Unit tests you are supposed to **Mock** certain Input/Situation and then Test against it